# Detecting if angle is more than 180 degrees

Tags: c, algorithm, math, computational-geometry, trigonometry

I'm working on a problem that the professor assigned, and I'm having a problem looking for a way to detect if the angle between 3 points is more than 180 degrees, e.g:

[image]

I want to detect if alpha is more than 180 degrees. Anyways, my professor has a code that solves the problem, but he has a function called zcross, but I don't exactly know how it works. Could anyone tell me? His code is here:

```
#include <fstream.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point {
    double  x;
    double  y;
    double  angle;
};

struct vector {
    double  i;
    double  j;
};

point   P[10000];
int     hull[10000];

int 
zcross (vector * u, vector * v)
{
    double  p = u->i * v->j - v->i * u->j;
    if (p > 0)
    return 1;
    if (p < 0)
    return -1;
    return 0;
}

int 
cmpP (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    if (((point *) a)->angle < ((point *) b)->angle)
    return -1;
    if (((point *) a)->angle > ((point *) b)->angle)
    return 1;
    return 0;
}

void 
main ()
{
    int     N, i, hullstart, hullend, a, b;
    double  midx, midy, length;
    vector  v1, v2;

    ifstream fin ("fc.in");
    fin >> N;
    midx = 0, midy = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        fin >> P[i].x >> P[i].y;
        midx += P[i].x;
        midy += P[i].y;
    }
    fin.close ();
    midx = (double) midx / N;
    midy = (double) midy / N;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        P[i].angle = atan2 (P[i].y - midy, P[i].x - midx);
    qsort (P, N, sizeof (P[0]), cmpP);

    hull[0] = 0;
    hull[1] = 1;
    hullend = 2;
    for (i = 2; i < N - 1; i++) {
        while (hullend > 1) {
            v1.i = P[hull[hullend - 2]].x - P[hull[hullend - 1]].x;
            v1.j = P[hull[hullend - 2]].y - P[hull[hullend - 1]].y;
            v2.i = P[i].x - P[hull[hullend - 1]].x;
            v2.j = P[i].y - P[hull[hullend - 1]].y;
            if (zcross (&v1, &v2) < 0)
                break;
            hullend--;
        }
        hull[hullend] = i;
        hullend++;
    }

    while (hullend > 1) {
        v1.i = P[hull[hullend - 2]].x - P[hull[hullend - 1]].x;
        v1.j = P[hull[hullend - 2]].y - P[hull[hullend - 1]].y;
        v2.i = P[i].x - P[hull[hullend - 1]].x;
        v2.j = P[i].y - P[hull[hullend - 1]].y;
        if (zcross (&v1, &v2) < 0)
            break;
        hullend--;
    }
    hull[hullend] = i;

    hullstart = 0;
    while (true) {
        v1.i = P[hull[hullend - 1]].x - P[hull[hullend]].x;
        v1.j = P[hull[hullend - 1]].y - P[hull[hullend]].y;
        v2.i = P[hull[hullstart]].x - P[hull[hullend]].x;
        v2.j = P[hull[hullstart]].y - P[hull[hullend]].y;
        if (hullend - hullstart > 1 && zcross (&v1, &v2) >= 0) {
            hullend--;
            continue;
        }
        v1.i = P[hull[hullend]].x - P[hull[hullstart]].x;
        v1.j = P[hull[hullend]].y - P[hull[hullstart]].y;
        v2.i = P[hull[hullstart + 1]].x - P[hull[hullstart]].x;
        v2.j = P[hull[hullstart + 1]].y - P[hull[hullstart]].y;
        if (hullend - hullstart > 1 && zcross (&v1, &v2) >= 0) {
            hullstart++;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    length = 0;
    for (i = hullstart; i <= hullend; i++) {
        a = hull[i];
        if (i == hullend)
            b = hull[hullstart];
        else
            b = hull[i + 1];
        length += sqrt ((P[a].x - P[b].x) * (P[a].x - P[b].x) + (P[a].y - P[b].y) * (P[a].y - P[b].y));
    }

    ofstream fout ("fc.out");
    fout.setf (ios: :fixed);
    fout.precision (2);
    fout << length << '\n';
    fout.close ();
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First, we know that if `sin(a)` is negative, then the angle is more than 180 degrees.

How do we find the sign of `sin(a)`? Here is where cross product comes into play.

First, let's define two vectors:

```
v1 = p1-p2
v2 = p3-p2
```

This means that the two vectors start at `p2` and one points to `p1` and the other points to `p3`.

Cross product is defined as:

```
(x1, y1, z1) x (x2, y2, z2) = (y1z2-y2z1, z1x2-z2x1, x1y2-x2y1)
```

Since your vectors are in 2d, then `z1` and `z2` are 0 and hence:

```
(x1, y1, 0) x (x2, y2, 0) = (0, 0, x1y2-x2y1)
```

That is why they call it *zcross* because only the z element of the product has a value other than 0.

Now, on the other hand, we know that:

```
||v1 x v2|| = ||v1|| * ||v2|| * abs(sin(a))
```

where `||v||` is the norm (size) of vector `v`. Also, we know that if the angle `a` is less than 180, then `v1 x v2` will point upwards (right hand rule), while if it is larger than 180 it will point down. So in your special case:

```
(v1 x v2).z = ||v1|| * ||v2|| * sin(a)
```

Simply put, if the z value of `v1 x v2` is positive, then `a` is smaller than 180. If it is negative, then it's bigger (The z value was `x1y2-x2y1`). If the cross product is 0, then the two vectors are parallel and the angle is either 0 or 180, depending on whether the two vectors have respectively same or opposite direction.

Comment: In 2D, what you are really doing is computing the "outer product", which is a more general concept than cross product and works in any number of dimensions.  They don't teach it in introductory linear algebra classes, which is a shame.  (The formula is mostly the same, just with no mention of "z" coordinates, so it's simpler.)

Answer (score 4):

zcross is using the sign of the [vector cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) (plus or minus in the z direction) to determine if the angle is more or less than 180 degrees, as you've put it.

Answer (score 1):

In 3D, find the cross product of the vectors, find the minimum length for the cross product which is basically just finding the smallest number of x, y and z.

If the smallest value is smaller than 0, the angle of the vectors is negative.

So in code:

```
float Vector3::Angle(const Vector3 &v) const
{
    float a = SquareLength();
    float b = v.SquareLength();
    if (a > 0.0f && b > 0.0f)
    {
        float sign = (CrossProduct(v)).MinLength();
        if (sign < 0.0f)
            return -acos(DotProduct(v) / sqrtf(a * b));
        else
            return acos(DotProduct(v) / sqrtf(a * b));
    }
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: I think its important to mention, that the function returns a angle between [-180°;180°] - not a angle between [0;360°] - works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be as follows:

calculate vector v1=p2-p1, v2 = p2 -p3. 
Then, use the cross-product formula : u.v = ||u|| ||v|| cos(theta)

Comment: How do you handle angles > 180°?

Comment: The sign tells you if it is more than 180°, doesn't it?